# How to install OpenCV in Linaro Android on Pandaboard

Tags: android, opencv, omap

I'm doing a project using OpenCV 2.3.1 and I want to embedded this on a pandaboard. So I'm looking for someone who can help me to instal opencv on Pandabord using Linaro Android 11.11 . If you have some link or if you can advise me I would appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run openCV on android I would suggest you learn about the java native interface, JNI. I have developed image processing algorithms on Android cell phones. You want to get Eclipse and install the SDK :http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

After that you need to install the Eclipse NDK in order to develop C/C++ code in your java apps, this gave me about x5 increase in performance: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

Finally you need to download and link the openCV C/C++ library to your projects:
http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html#android-binary-package

You should also check out the google Play Store, they have some cool OpenSource projects you can look at.